# I want to make a command that can be used with a specific role

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roles

I want to make a command that can be used only by specific roles.

Here's my code:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => { 
  if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`rpg hunt`)) {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      message.channel.send(`**Reminder** <@${message.author.id}> <a:hunt:745296491907645527> RPG HUNT <a:hunt:745296491907645527>`)
    }, 60000); 
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a `GuildMember` has a specific role by using the `.has` method on the `Collection GuildMember.roles.cache`.

---

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("rpg hunt") && message.member.roles.cache.has("ROLE ID")) {
        // Code
    };
});
```